# How to Disable Spring Batch Meta Data in spring 5.0.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I googled a lot and trying to follow this doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/5.0.1/reference/html/whatsnew.html#whatsNew

But not able to find a way to disable spring batch meta data.

Even I tried not to use @EnableBatchProcessing but still getting this err:

> for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw
> exception [Request processing failed:
> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
> PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID,
> PARAMETER_NAME, PARAMETER_TYPE, PARAMETER_VALUE, IDENTIFYING from
> BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?]] with root
> cause java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column
> 'PARAMETER_NAME' in 'field list'

If there is any code reference or tutorial please suggest.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine any idea?

Comment: I added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "disable" metadata. A `Job` always requires a `JobRepository` to report its meta-data to (unless you implement the `Job` interface yourself, which is not the goal in the first place if you decide to use Spring Batch).

Now starting from v5, Spring Batch only provides a JDBC based implementation of the `JobRepository`. The in-memory Map-based implementation was removed. Therefore, you have to use the JDBC implementation (which is the default and which requires a JDBC datasource), or provide a custom implementation of `JobRepository` yourself.

In the case of using the default JDBC based `JobRepository`, the datasource could be an in-memory one (like H2, HSQLDB, etc).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mohamoud, so it means we cannot disable metadata starting from spring 5. In my case, I am using another database for my reader.  So I am trying to make 2 data sources but am stuck. I have posted this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76249173/how-to-use-2-datasources-in-spring-batch-5-0-1 Can you please have a look.