# How to use 2 datasources in spring batch 5.0.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, java-17

I am trying to add 2 data sources to my spring batch project (spring boot based). One is for the spring batch job reader JPA repository and the other one is for spring batch metadata (since we cannot disable metadata in version 5).

My app.properties is like this

```
    spring.reader.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springbootcrudexample
    spring.reader.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    spring.reader.datasource.username=root
    spring.reader.datasource.password=
    
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;SCHEMA=BATCH
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
    spring.datasource.username=sa
    spring.datasource.password=
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    spring.h2.console.enabled=true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

My DataSourceConfiguration class is this

```
    @Configuration
    @Component
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
            entityManagerFactoryRef = "readerEntityManagerFactory",
            transactionManagerRef = "readerTransactionManager")
    public class ReaderDataSourceConfiguration {
    
        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties("spring.reader.datasource")
        public DataSourceProperties readerDataSourceProperties() {
            return new DataSourceProperties();
        }
    
        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties("spring.reader.datasource.configuration")
        public DataSource readerDataSource() {
            return readerDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                    .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
        }
    
        @Bean(name = "readerEntityManagerFactory")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean readerEntityManagerFactory(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
            return builder
                    .dataSource(readerDataSource())
                    .packages("com.batch.job.reader") // giving only reader entities package
                    .build();
        }
    
        @Bean(name = "readerTransactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager readerTransactionManager(
                final @Qualifier("readerEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean readerEntityManagerFactory) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(readerEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
        }
    
    }
```

My reader is fairly simple:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(//basePackages = "com.javatodev.api.repository.user", not sure what will come here so commenting it our
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef= "transactionManager")
public class BatchMetaDataSourceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties batchDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.configuration")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return batchDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer h2DatabasePopulator() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        populator.addScript(
                new ClassPathResource("org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql"));
        populator.setContinueOnError(true);
        populator.setIgnoreFailedDrops(true);

        DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        initializer.setDatabasePopulator(populator);
        initializer.setDataSource(dataSource());

        return initializer;
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .packages("com.rbc.services.accountmapper.loader")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            final @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }
}
```

My spring config file is as given below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private AProcessor processor;
    @Autowired
    private AWriter writer;
    @Autowired
    private JpaPagingItemReader<OriginEntity> reader;
    
    @Autowired
    private LoaderJobExecutionListener jobExecutionListener;

    @Autowired
    private ItemProcessorExecutionListener itemProcessorExecutionListener;
    @Autowired
    private ItemReaderExecutionListener itemReaderExecutionListener;

    @Value("${chunkSize}")
    private Integer chunkSize;



    @Bean
    public Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository,
                      PlatformTransactionManager readerTransactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("accountMapperDataLoaderStep", jobRepository)
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .<OriginEntity, DestinationEntity>chunk(chunkSize, readerTransactionManager)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .faultTolerant()
                .retryLimit(1)
                .retry(ArithmeticException.class)
                .listener(itemReaderExecutionListener)
                .listener(itemProcessorExecutionListener)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job runJob(JobRepository jobRepository,
                      PlatformTransactionManager readerTransactionManager) {
        return new JobBuilder("accountMapperDataLoaderJob", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step1(jobRepository, readerTransactionManager))
                .listener(jobExecutionListener)
                //.flow(step1)
                // .end()
                .build();
    }
}
```

My Reader is as given below. I am trying to use readerEntityManagerFactory from ReaderDataSourceConfiguration class to use as MySQL daatsource with reader but somehow it is using primary (H2) datasource.

```
@Configuration
public class AReader {

    @Value("${chunkSize}")
    private Integer chunkSize;

    @Autowired
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean readerEntityManagerFactory;

    @Bean(destroyMethod="")
    public JpaPagingItemReader<OriginAccount> reader() {
        return new JpaPagingItemReaderBuilder<OriginAccount>()
                .name("Account")
                .entityManagerFactory(readerEntityManagerFactory.getObject())
                .queryString("query")
                .pageSize(chunkSize)
                .build();
    }

}
```

When I am trying to run the application , my application is crashing:

```
    batch.ItemReaderExecutionListener : Exception occurred while reading.
    jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Converting `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException` to JPA `PersistenceException` : could not prepare statement
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "READER_TABLE" not found; SQL statement:
```

I think my reader datasource is also trying to use h2, which should not be.
I am not able to figure out what I am missing. Tnx for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder that your builder methods are empty (`.create().build()`). Try replacing your configuration class that sets up both datasources like so:

```java
    @Bean(name = "springDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    @Primary
    public DataSourceProperties springDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "springReaderDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.reader.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties springReaderDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "springDataSource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("springDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties springDataSourceProperties) {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                                .driverClassName(springDataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
                                .url(springDataSourceProperties.getUrl())
                                .password(springDataSourceProperties.getPassword())
                                .username(springDataSourceProperties.getUsername())
                                .build();
    }

    @Bean("readerDataSource")
    public DataSource readerDataSource(@Qualifier("springReaderDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties springReaderDataSourceProperties) {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                                .driverClassName(springReaderDataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
                                .url(springReaderDataSourceProperties.getUrl())
                                .password(springReaderDataSourceProperties.getPassword())
                                .username(springReaderDataSourceProperties.getUsername())
                                .build();
    }
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi @Manu, i edited my code and also exception can you please have a look.

Comment: Check your application.properties file. Are you setting the right properties? In your datasource configuration classes you use "spring.batch.datasource" for Spring Batch and "spring.reader.datasource" for your Reader. But your application.properties file uses "spring.reader.datasource" and "spring.datasource". Also, please share your Job Configuration so I can see how you create the reader etc. You marked Spring Batch Datasource as @Primary (= H2), so probably you still have to tell your Job / reader to use the non-primary DataSource.

Comment: Hi @Manu, i updated the code, you were right so i removed batch keyword. I also added the batch config class. I am expecting PlatformTransactionManager readerTransactionManager to be used in for processing chunks from MySQL db. Also I added Reader. Please have a look . ty